# Activator.CreateInstance, : Constructor on type 'Pastel.Evolution.PurchaseOrder' not found

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

I have now gotten to the point where I am trying to create an instance of a class in the assembly I have loaded.

```
 object obj= Activator.CreateInstance(purchaseOrder,
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                        BindingFlags.Instance,
                                        null, new object[] { purchaseOrderDocumentBase }, null);
```

I keep getting the Error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Constructor on type
>   'Pastel.Evolution.PurchaseOrder' not found.

What I read up already:

Most of the people are referring to the constructors being private. The type I am loading has 4 constructors all public.  Some refer to the Type not having a default constructor, which I thing is the problem.

I have tried to Invoke the first Constructor which has no parameters :

```
constractor.Invoke(purchaseOrder, null);
```

I then get the following error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Object does not match
>   target type.

Can anyone shed some light on this please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears you have combined multiple projects and the source code for the 2nd project doesn't match the dll.  Usually this occurs when the 2nd project gets changed but the dll doesn't get updated.  Check if both projects are set to release/debug.  I usually set my projects to debug mode. Then make sure the reference for the 2nd project is set to the debug folder and not the release folder.

Comment: The full background of what I am trying to achieve is as follow :
We are integrating to an external program with WCF services. We then have different customers on different versions of the external program. I have 6 versions off an externally created dll, I have no access to the dll's code. What I am trying to do is to load the specific assembly the customer need and then create instances of the classes in the dll, then from there I should have access to the methods in the dll.

In short I want to make my integration service backwards compatible.

Comment: Using Solution explorer can you see the functions inside the dll.  If you can make sure the parameters of the functions match with you code that call the methods.

Comment: I can see all the classes and methods inside the classes. The problem is, I can't Create an Instance of the class.

Comment: If the class is static you can't create an instance.  If it is not static you should be able to go to Solution explorer and in the reference objects find your library/class.  Find the constructor for the class and see the required parameters.  You are not calling the constructor with the correct parameters.